# Why won't my print function won't display the elements in either sub node of my linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, cout

I have been at this for days now and I just can't seem to find out why my last two things won't print. The code is quite long so I won't post it all , but if you need it I am willing to provide the entire source.

Basically I call the print function after adding 1 element to each of the listed elements. It will print them all EXCEPT the last two Spouse and Child. Those two are the most complicated as they are their own lists as well. When I tested the for loop for child it showed that no matter how many children I add to the Vector it reads the size as 0. Why is this?

```
void AddressNode::PrintFull()
{

cout << setfill(' ') << endl;
cout << setw(15) << "UID " << "ID" << setfill('0') << setw(3) << id_ <<  setfill(' ')<< endl;
cout << setw(15) << "NAME:" << firstName_ << " " << lastName_ << endl;
cout << setw(15) << "Address1:" << address_ << endl;
cout << setw(15) << "City:" << city_<< " "  << endl;
cout << setw(15) << "State:" << state_<< " "  << endl;
cout << setw(15) << "Zip:" << zip_<< " "  << endl;
cout << setw(15) << "Date_Birth:" << dob_<< " "  << endl;
cout << setw(15) << "Date_Death:" << dod_<< " "  << endl;
cout << setw(15) << "Date_Wedding:" << dow_<< " "  << endl;
cout << setw(15) << "Spouse:" << (spouse_ ? spouse_->GetFirstName() : "") << " " << (spouse_ ? spouse_-> GetLastName() : "") << endl;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < children_.size(); i++)
{
    cout << setw(15) << "Child: " << i << ": " << children_[i]->GetFirstName()<< " " << children_[i]->GetLastName()<<  endl;
}
}

private:
std::string firstName_;
std::string lastName_;
std::string city_ ;
std::string state_  ;
std::string zip_  ;
std::string dob_ ;
std::string dow_;
std::string dod_;
std::string address_;
std::string spouseTempString;
std::vector<AddressNode*> children_;
AddressNode* spouse_;
unsigned int id_;


void AddressNode::AddChild(AddressNode& child)
{
    vector<AddressNode*>::iterator iter;
    if((iter = find(children_.begin(), children_.end(), &child)) != children_.end())
        return;

    children_.push_back(&child);

    if (spouse_)
        spouse_->AddChild(child);
}





public:
    AddressNode(const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName, int id)
        :  children_(), id_(id)
    {
        firstName_= "";
        firstName_+= firstName;
        lastName_="";
        lastName_+= lastName;

    }
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. That pushing of a pointer worries me, and will be the problem if e.g. you call `AddChild` passing a reference to a local variable.

Comment: difficult to see the context e.g. owner of the objects that AddressNode* points to.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough code here to tell, but passing an object by reference and then storing its address is always fishy.
If a stack object gets passed to that function you'll get all kind of weird results.

Since your error only occur on pointer objects, I'm even more inclined to think you've got memory management issues somewhere.

If you really want to store a pointer, pass the pointer in the first place, or pass a const reference and store a copy?